# Сложение 3 чисел с помощью editText в android

Tags: java, android

Делаю так:

```
Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        Text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        Text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
        Text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText03);

        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    a = Integer.parseInt(Text1.getText().toString());
                    b = Integer.parseInt(Text2.getText().toString());
                    c = Integer.parseInt(Text3.getText().toString());

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    a = 0;
                    b = 0;
                    c = 0;
                }              
                d = a+b+c;
                Text.setText("Результат сложения = "+d);
            }});
    }}
```

=========================xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android: descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<EditText
 android:id="@+id/EditText01"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android: inputType="number">

<EditText
 android:id="@+id/EditText02"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android: inputType="number">

<EditText
 android:id="@+id/EditText03"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android: inputType="number">

<Button
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/text"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

В первых двух edittext когда вводишь значение и нажимаешь рассчет, то все работает. А вот с третьей всегда какие нить касяки типа: когда вводишь третье знаачение и нажимаешь расчет,то оно не выводится, а когда его из поля удаляешь и нажимаешь рассчет, то оно защитывается... не понимаю что такое? Как с этим бороться?

Comment: проверьте разметку, id правильные?

Comment: все правильные...

Comment: покажите её, может что то увижу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика приложения у вас такова, что если хотя бы в одном из полей нет данных результат будет равен 0, так как все значения сетятся в ноль. Вот как вы можете реализовать расчет:

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(Text1.getText().toString())) {
                a = Integer.parseInt(Text1.getText().toString());
            } else {
                a = 0;
            }

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(Text2.getText().toString())) {
                b = Integer.parseInt(Text2.getText().toString());
            } else {
                b = 0;
            }

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(Text3.getText().toString())) {
                c = Integer.parseInt(Text3.getText().toString());
            } else {
                c = 0;
            }

            d = a + b + c;
            Text.setText("Result = " + d);
        }
    });
```

Comment: ошибок никаких, но ответ Text.setText("Result = " + d); вообще не выводит....какойто касяк в проверке if

Comment: это вы о моем коде говорите? Если да, то странно, я его проверял, все корректно работает. Попробуйте наставить выводов сообщений в лог с помощью Log.d() и посмотрите что происходит или отладьте код с помощью breakpoints.